# how to get header and set token in typescript /angular 2

Tags: typescript, header, angular2-routing, httpresponse, angular2-services

How to get header and extract authentication token and set it in local storage in angular 2.
Below is register.component.ts code::

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, 
RequestMethod} from '@angular2/http';


import { AlertService, UserService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id.toString(),
templateUrl: 'register.component.html'
})

export class RegisterComponent {
model: any = {};
loading = false;

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private alertService: AlertService) { }

register() {
    this.loading = true;
    console.log(this.model.mobilenumber);
    this.userService.create(this.model)
          .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.status===200){
                    this.alertService.success('Registration successfull click link in email to activate account', true);
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
                else{
                  console.log(data);
                this.loading = false;
                this.alertService.error('Try with other email', true);
              }
            },
            error => {
              console.log(data);
                this.alertService.error("Error");
                this.loading = false;
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);

            });
}
```

}

Below is service code which interacts with backend rest api::

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserDetails } from '../_models/index';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
@Injectable()
 export class UserService {
 public  registerUserUrl="http://localhost:8080/ToDo/userRegister";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  create(user: UserDetails) {
  console.log("in create user"+user);
  return this.http.post(this.registerUserUrl,user);
       }}}
```

How to get header and extract authentication token and set it in local storage in angular 2.
pl help iam not having much knowledge of type script new to it

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use Angular HttpInterceptor. More information at official Angular documentation site: [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses).

From the official docs:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

export class TimingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const started = Date.now();
    return next
      .handle(req)
      .do(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
          console.log(`Request for ${req.urlWithParams} took ${elapsed} ms.`);

         // Here they console.log() the data but actually you could do everything

        }
     });
 }
}
```

Comment: where to add this code and how can i use this in my code

Comment: You need to read the documentation - it's actually mention in https://angular.io/guide/http#providing-your-interceptor.  I mean - you need to write the interceptor + add a declaration in `NgModule`